# excel formula to show variable name instead of sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to display a letter "X" in the cell, but with a formula to hold the SUM. attached screenshot. is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use IF and force the criteria to be TRUE using TRUE.

```
=IF(TRUE,"X",SUM(8+2))
```

You could also use a customer number format that would allow you to keep the formula exactly as is, and still display an X

See image below.[image]

Comment: really useful, thank you! it works. quick question, why the 3 times "x"?

Comment: the ; separator is for different number types,  positives ; negatives ; zero ; text     check out https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/ for more info, theres loads of cool things you can do